# Count number of lines in a text file

Tags: c++, mfc

I need to count the number of lines in a text file. This is the code I have right now.

```
CStdioFile sampleFile;
sampleFile.Open("test.txt",CFile::modeRead );
long length = 1;
CString row("");
while(sampleFile.ReadString(row))
{
    length++;
}
```

This isn't working. I'm not getting the correct value of the number of lines in the text file.What is wrong with this?

Thanks.

Comment: You're getting always one greater than the correct value, right? Initialize `length` with `0`, not `1`.

Comment: Even if it was initialised to 1, the value should be off the mark by 1. In my case, I have a text file with 30 odd lines and the value of length comes out to be 2.

Comment: Maybe it's a line ending problem: change your program to print out the contents of row on each loop iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To read Unicode text files you might want to check CStdioFile derived implementation: CStdioFileEx from codeproject:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4119/CStdioFile-derived-class-for-multibyte-and-Unicode

Answer (score 1):

`length` should be initialized to `0` instead of `1`, because you have yet to read the first line:

```
CString row;
long length = 0;
while (sampleFile.ReadString(row))
{
    length++;
}
```

Comment: Even if it was initialised to 1, the value should be off the mark by 1. In my case, I have a text file with 30 odd lines and the value of length comes out to be 2.

Comment: @molu, the problem may come from elsewhere then. What's the encoding used in your file?

Comment: The text is saved as a Unicode file.

edit: it work on ANSI encoded text files! But I need it to work on Unicode files.

Comment: UCS-2, then? Is the `UNICODE` preprocessor symbol defined in your project?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm new to this. I'm working in Visual Studio 2010. How do I check if the UNICODE preprocessor symbol has been defined in my project?

Comment: @molu, open your project's properties, then under `Configuration Properties > General`, check the value of the `Character Set` option. It should be `Use Unicode Character Set` for your code to properly read UCS-2 encoded files.

Comment: In my project's properties, the "Character Set" property has been set to  "Use Unicode Character Set". But the problem remains.

Answer (score 1):

Try to count from 0:

```
long length = 0;
```